# querying array of object in PHP mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Hi I'm beginner in mongodb, my document looks like this :

```
{
        '_id': ObjectId("599d142a02ae238"),
        'name': 'Product One',
        'status': 'in stock',
        'prices': [ {
                'currency': 'USD',
                'amount': 1000
            }, {
                'currency': 'THB',
                'amount': 3000
            } ]
}
```

I would like to do a query to search for product in specific price range and specific currency. My query is looks like this:

```
[
    'prices.amount' => ['$gte' => 2000, '$lte' => 5000], 
    'prices.currency' => 'USD',
]
```

if I run this query it should not return any value, as the product price in that range is not in USD. But it did return the data. How is the correct query? Any advice pls? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"prices":{"$elemMatch":{"amount": {"$gte":2000, "$lte":5000}, "currency":"USD"}}}

Comment: you need to use the elemMatch to iterate through the array elements